# Wallet account value

Tags: wallet

I have some money in my Bitcoin wallet. I'm wondering about is the monetary value which increases and decreases as the value of 1 Bitcoin fluctuates?

Answer (score 1):

Typically wallets will give you your balance in bitcoins as well as a conversion of that balance into other currencies (like USD). Since the exchange rate of BTC to USD is changing all the time, your balance expressed in USD (or whatever currency it shows) will change all the time as well.

[Here's a link](https://www.coinbase.com/charts?locale=en) to a chart and current conversion rates.

Your balance in bitcoin however will remain exactly the same until you make another outgoing transaction or receive one.

Comment: Blockonomics wallet watcher will show your total balance in currency of ur choice and in bitcoin. You just need to enter you public address http://imgur.com/wJNJaf4